# Are Icons (PNG) that display numbers or letters generated dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web

When there are notification icons to indicate a number for example, are those icons generated dynamically, or are they stored somewhere and the proper icon is fetched? It seems like the obvious answer is that there are icons stored labeled with the correct number and fetched locally or remotely. But if there is a way to generate it dynamically, that would be great. Any help would be appreciated!

Here are some examples:

[image]
[image]

Comment: These typically are not icons, but rather styled spans or divs whereby the content of the element is the number, or any piece of content really. As a small example, see how tags are implemented in Bulma: https://bulma.io/documentation/elements/tag/. Now just imagine the tag being circular and red, similar to your image above.

Comment: I will check it out thanks! That makes a lot more sense

Answer (score 0):

You can use fontawesome to try making the layer counter.

[Support for layer counters](https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome/issues/74)

[Layering, Text, & Counters](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/layering)